# What's it called when you refer to a member of a group by a modified version of the group name?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for words like Amazonian, Googler, Harvardian -- monikers that mean "member of this group" that are just derivations of the group name? They seem to usually end in "-ian" or "-er" but not always (I guess Meta employees are called ["metamates"](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/02/15/technology/metamates-meta-facebook.html) now, poor things).

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/585375/19046